# ASP.NET web page freeze on loading on 'Thread was being aborted' exception

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting Thread was being aborted Exception on calling an API. Though I have handled it in the catch block and execution of code continues and completes properly, the page in the browser is still stuck on loading, it won't render the output.
Please help me understand the cause.

```
try
{
     //API call rasing Thread was being aborted Exception
}
Catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
{
     Thread.ResetAbort();
}

//some code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following in your web.config file

```
<configuration> <system.web>

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />

</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the value in seconds or in minutes?

Comment: it is seconds. 360 means 6 minutes

Comment: Do you have "Sever Transfer" in your API call ? For Server.Transfer, please use the Server.Execute method instead

Comment: No, I'm not calling Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect. It's only a function call of an API.

Comment: Are you calling a https API ? or just http API ?

Comment: Https API, Also i'm getting the same error on my local machine when I debug it, but it won't freeze the web page, the page is freezing only on server.

Comment: please try whether the error still persists if you ignore the ResetAbort (remark the line).

Comment: Can you tell me the URL of the https API ? Thanks

Comment: No, I can not, for confidentiality purposes.